# Swift Convert large number to small number and attach 'K' or 'M'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsnumberformatter

I want to convert a big number to a small number with NumberFormatter.

```
910 => 91
45893 => 45
```

but my program doesn't work for this example:

```
910394529348 => 0
```

My code is correct for small number, but when my variable 'powCalc' is greater than 7 digits NumberFormatter returns 0. Actually I think for type of multiplier ( NSNumber ) and limitation of that. Is it correct?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let maximumSignificantDigits: Double = 2
var myValue = 910394529348
let len = ceil (log10 ( Double(myValue)))
var short = Int(len - maximumSignificantDigits)

short -= (short % 3)

var positiveFormat = ""

switch short {
case 0:
    positiveFormat = ""
case 3:
    positiveFormat = "K"
case 6:
    positiveFormat = "M"
default:
    positiveFormat = "etc"
}

let powCalc = 1.0 / pow(10, Double(short))

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.multiplier =  powCalc as NSNumber!
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

numberFormatter.positiveFormat = "0" + positiveFormat

stride(from: 0, to: myValue, by: myValue / 10).map {counter in
    print(counter, Double(counter) * powCalc, numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: counter))!)
}
```

Return for 'myValue' 0!

But if you change the myValue to 523478 or something else the program work.

Comment: What value does `powCalc` have?

Comment: `let powCalc = 1.0 / pow(10, Double(short))`?

Comment: It seems that (for reasons unknown to me), NSNumberFormatter does not work with multipliers less than 1.0E-7.

Comment: @AshleyMills @paper1111 This value: `let powCalc = 1.0 / pow(10, Double(short))`

Comment: @MartinR I think your right. What can I do for this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can use (NS)ByteCountFormatter instead? – Otherwise scale the number *before* passing it to the number formatter.

Comment: I was meant what actual value was in `powCalc`, rather than the expression, although it seems like @MartinR has hit the nail on the head.